# Error while running Django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

When I run django project in pycharm or cmd, I get this error. What Should I do?

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.4.1\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/manage.py runserver 8000
    Validating models...

```
0 errors found
August 15, 2014 - 13:58:27
Django version 1.6.5, using settings 'untitled.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x022A32B8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 127, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 167, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 109, in __init__
    super(WSGIServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 429, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 113, in server_bind
    super(WSGIServer, self).server_bind()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 135, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 460, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 6: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: This looks a little bit like [Issue18109](http://bugs.python.org/issue18109) for me, but that should be solved... Does your hostname contain unicode characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have not tested it**, but I suppose this is a python error. The stack trace you have provided suggests, that the UnicodeDecodeError gets triggerd when your hostname gets copied into a python unicode string.

Please check if the hostname of the machine you are working on contains unicode characters.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109244/unicodedecodeerror-with-runserver) seems to be the same issue as yours. In the post the python [Issue9377](http://bugs.python.org/issue9377) is referenced which is still open.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your **settings.py manage.py wsgi.py** etc. for the non-ascii literals.

2) When found add

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the beginning of your files

3) And add u at the beggining of strings that contains non-ascii literals

> eg: **u**"This characters are not unicode : **üşiğç**"

///**for python 2.x**

Comment: Sorry, but **no**: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083111/python3-encoding-declaration

Comment: there are no non-ascii characters. and i just installed and did not change anything

Comment: python 3.x? i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify host name. Migth be your host name contains some non-ascii literals.
Seems that you use Windows 7 OS.