# Django 1.9.5 tutorial error runserver.py

Tags: python, django

I'm reading the Django tutorial and I would try to code one my little example based on it.
When I type:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

I had this error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x103da9488>
```

I have only one simple url with one "Hello Wordl" simple view. Could someone help me?
(I'm running Python 3.5.1 and Django 1.9.5).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicodedecodeerror with runserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109244/unicodedecodeerror-with-runserver)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem that emerges when a unicode character not found in ascii is encountered. There are solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109244/unicodedecodeerror-with-runserver) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324014/error-while-runing-django-app)